# Notification banner with auto close need “close(x)” button?

Tags: usability, user-research, ux-field, ux-designer, human-interface-guideline

The notifications banner that displayed on top of the screen will disappears automatically in time delay.

But I have seen many notification banners with auto close and close(x) button. Is the close(x) button is necessary?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Yes, because you can't know how "fast" the user is in reading these. A user shouldn't be forced to see the messages until your timer has ran out, he should be given the option to close them as fast as he wants to.

Answer (score 1):

This question already has been asked earlier and this should clear your doubt. It shares two perspectives where it can be useful and sometimes totally unnecessary defeating the purpose of the alert.

[Why do error and success messages have a close button?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/20747/why-do-error-and-success-messages-have-a-close-button)

However, I personally feel that the close button would be necessary in cases where the alert is obscuring a CTA on your app / website. For example, say this comes over the header - now due to this the other actions on the header are not clickable. To get back to the header the user would like to close this. In such cases the close button is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Success messages should automatically fade out and disappear, because success is what the user will expect so we should not force them to manually dismiss it.

The others message types ***will*** be of interest to the user, because they will not be expecting them. Ideally the user will correct whatever is wrong before continuing in the solution.

The user can dismiss these messages manually *if* they want to get rid of them, but use natural interaction points in the system to automatically close messages which are no longer appropriate, e.g. primary commit buttons, navigation to other pages, etc.